# calling chain method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code but it is constantly giving me errors :

> TypeError: container("accounts").atPosition("#left-top") is undefined

the code is :

```
function container(name, position) {
    return {
        pos: null,
        atPosition: function(position) {

            $(position).html(this.newContainer());
            //$(position+" .main").html("yes");
            this.pos = position;
        },
        populateData: function(rdata) {
            $("#left-top .main").html(rdata);
        },
        newContainer: function() {
            //alert(this.pos);
            return '<h3>' + name.toTitleCase() + '</h3>\
                <div class="main">\
                </div>';
        }
    };
}

container('accounts').atPosition('#left-top').populateData("yahoo!!!!");​
```

Why am I receiving this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: `atPosition` returns nothing (`undefined`), so you can't call `.populateData` on it

Comment: I had written an answer before that is a simple example of chaining function that doesn't use jQuery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272758/chain-of-functions-in-javascript/11276015#11276015

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You supposed to return `this` from functions for chaining. By default function return undefined (if you dont use `new operator`) . by returning this from function which don't have any thing to return will help in chaining.

```
function container(name, position) {
    return {
        pos: null,
        atPosition: function(position) {
            $(position).html(this.newContainer());
            //$(position+" .main").html("yes");
            this.pos = position;

            return this;
        },
        populateData: function(rdata) {
            $("#left-top .main").html(rdata);
            return this;
        },
        newContainer: function() {
            //alert(this.pos);
            return '<h3>' + name.toTitleCase() + '</h3>\
                <div class="main">\
                </div>';
        }
    };
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

The function you assign to `atPosition` doesn't have a `return` statement.

So when you call `atPosition('#left-top')`, you get the default return value of `undefined`

You need to return the object you wish to call `populateData` on (which should be `this`)

Answer (score 1):

function chaining is **not a special javascript syntax**, if you want, you can implement it in Java, Python or anything that supports OOP.

`a.functionX().functionY()` works because `functionX()` returns again **an object** which has a **method** called `functionY()`

in your case, `functionX()` should return the same object it is invoked on, therefore `return this;` will fix your problem

**But this is not the end of the story!!!**

@Rich S mentioned in his answer:

> In order to make chaining work, you need to "return this;" at the end of any functions you want to chain.

which is **not necessary true**, chaining will work as long as you return **an object(or any object)**, here is an example:

```js
var str ="abc";
var strFromChain = str.replace('a','x').toUpperCase();
// use function chainning
document.write(strFromChain+'\n');
// result should be XBC

var str1 = "abc";
str1.replace('a','x');
var str1NotFromChain = str1.toUpperCase();
// if replace() returned this, str1NotFromChain should also be XBC
document.write(str1NotFromChain)
// but is it???????
```

Obviously `replace()` method of `str` did not return `this` instead it returned a new string with a different value, and this is easy to understand since **strings are immutables**, no matter what methods you call on `str`, its value will always be `"abc"`.

I am just making a point here, **it's not necessary for chaining method to return `this`, it can return a new object if it wants to**. Even though online tutorials teach you to use `this` when implementing chaining functions (ie [javascript.issexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/)) you should always pay attention to what is being returned when using a third party library(ie route chainning in [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html))

Answer (score 0):

Chaining doesn't happen automatically.

In order to make chaining work, you need to "return this;" at the end of any functions you want to chain.

In reality, all you're doing is calling the function on whatever you return. If you do "return this;" then you end up with a nice chaining syntax that affects the same object.

The jQuery developer guide is a good place to get quality JavaScript tips from, given your question, I'd recommend looking at http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Maintaining_Chainability