# Javascript multiple methods

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to figure out how to do something like this

```
SomeClass = {

    confirm: function(){
        if(!confirm('Sure?'))
        {
            return false;
        }
    },

    someMethod: function(){
        alert("OK");
    }

}
```

And this is what I actually want to do

```
SomeClass.confirm().someMethod();
```

In fact i need to confirm an action just by adding  .confirm() in front of the actual method. Is that even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling chain method in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049412/calling-chain-method-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SomeClass = {

    confirm: function(){
        if(!confirm('Sure?'))
        {
            this.status=false;
            return this;
        }
    },

    someMethod: function(){
        if(this.status){
            alert("OK");
        }
    }

}
```

This kind of method chaining is only possible if you return the object itself. You can use status to indicate whether the user confirmed or not.

You could also return just an object with the appropriate `somemethod`, although I suspect you want the method chaining to be more general than this:

```
SomeClass = {

    confirm: function(){
        if(!confirm('Sure?'))
        {
            return {someMethod:function(){alert("Canceled");}};
        }
        return {someMethod:function(){alert("OK");}};
    }

}
```

Ideally though, you would make your objects through a constructor function, and the confirm method would return a **new** instance of `SomeClass` with the `status` flag set to true or false.

Answer (score 3):

To do a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), you need to return the object itself from each function call.  That means restructuring your if logic:

```
SomeClass = {

wasConfirmed: false,

confirm: function(){
    this.wasConfirmed = confirm('Sure?');

    return this;
},

someMethod: function(){
    if(this.wasConfirmed) alert("OK");
}

}
```

Comment: Although you'll need some mechanism to clear the `wasConfirmed` flag too.

Comment: Correct.  The OP didn't really indicate where/when that should happen though so I left it as part of the constructor only.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var SomeClass = {
  state: null,

  confirm: function(){
    this.state = confirm('Sure?');    

    return this;
  },

  someMethod: function() {
    alert(this.state ? 'OK' : 'Error');
  }
};

SomeClass.confirm().someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to chain method calls in the way you described:

```
SomeClass.confirm().someMethod();
```

if your confirm method returns anything other than the `SomeClass` object that has the `someMethod()` defined.

You have probably seen things like this in jQuery:

```
// trigger click handlers of the element with id="id" and hide it:
$("#id").click().hide();
```

It works because the `click()` method returns the same object on which it was itself invoked on, so that the `hide()` method could be called on **that** returned object. Methods that return anything other than a jQuery object cannot be chained even in jQuery (only as the last method in chain).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want any action to be "confirmable" then you could write a class which takes the message to display tyo the user, and the action to perform if it's "confirmed"

```
var Confirmer = {

  confirm: function(msg, action){
       if(confirm(msg)){
          action();
       }
  }

}
```

You would then call it like:

```
Confirmer.confirm("Are you sure?", function(){ alert("hello"); });
```

With the second parameter any function you want called after the user confirms.